# Randomised output for the mode if there are 2 or more modes in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Suppose I have a list:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

There are 2 modes here, 1 and 2. How would I make it so my function returns either 1 or 2 at random so it would return 1 sometimes and 2 the other times. Or if there were 3 or more modes in the list it would return 1 of these at random. I already have a function which returns the mode from this list but it returns 1 every time.

```
def my_mode(alist):
    counter = dict()
    highest = -1
    high_item = []
    for item in alist:
        if item not in counter:
            counter[item] = 1
        else:
            counter[item] = counter[item] + 1
        if counter[item] > highest:
            highest = counter[item]
            high_item = item
    return high_item
```

or alternatively you can use `statistics.mode(a)` but this still doesn't randomize the output between 1 and 2.

Comment: Please add an explicit expected output to your post so that it is easier for everybody to understand and comment and give a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`statistics.multimode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode), which returns a list:

> Return a list of the most frequently occurring values in the order
> they were first encountered in the data. Will return more than one
> result if there are multiple modes or an empty list if the data is
> empty

Then, use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to randomly select one of those modes.

```
import statistics
import random
a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
modes = statistics.multimode(a)
print(random.choice(modes))
```